# End a for loop in the middle of the code using laravel

Tags: php, laravel, foreach

My page looks like this:

```
    @foreach
//create a div here
//and the div needs to use the outside function like
<input value="{{ showText }}"> // there is a form as well
// and the foreach ends.
@endforeach

<?php
//and the function is here.
function showText(){
//connect to database
//get the required information
//return the information
}
```

Now, the `showText()` function returns an id and that is what is used to update the info in the database.
But, Due to the `@foreach`, the showText() function returns nothing and Laravel shows an error that id can't be null or something like that. When I used PHP some time ago for the same thing, I could do something like:

```
<?php
for(){
?>
<div> Get the data through AJAX </div>
<?php
}
```

So, How do I do the same thing using laravel?

Comment: Did you try to write id returns from showText into variable?

Comment: @Sakezzz Thank You very much that was it!!! :-) :-) :-)

Comment: Glad it helped.